# WebComponentsReady not re-triggered

Tags: polymer

I have my main element using the flatiron-element to redirect my user:

```
....
<template if="{{route != null}}">
  <template if="{{route == 'home' || route == ''}}">
    <home-element structure="{{home}}"></home-element>
  </template>
  <template if="{{route == 'research'}}">
    <research-element structure="{{research}}"></research-element>
  </template>
  <template if="{{route == 'highlights'}}">
    <!-- <highlights-element></highlights-element> -->
  </template>
</template>
....

....
Polymer('research-element', {
      name: 'research',
      ready: function(){
        // wait for the WebComponent to be ready to hook up jquery
        var self = this;
         addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
          window.console.log($('#'+self.name+'-affix'));
           $('#'+self.name+'-affix').affix();
         });
 ....
```

1- On login (#home), the user get directed to the 'home-element', and the WebComponentsReady gets fired properly.

2- If I want to go to another page (#research), the users gets directed to the 'research-element'. The catch is that WebComponentsReady is not re-fired once the 'research-element' is ready.

Is it expected or am I doing something wrong?

In addition, it there any good way to cache the elements once they have been loaded?

Best,
Nicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `polymer-ready` event is a signal to the outside world that imports have loaded, custom elements are upgraded, and Polymer has finished its setup. You should not be listening for it inside your elements. It's only relevant to use in the main app (e.g. index.html).

Instead, use the [`attached`/`detached` lifecycle callbacks](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods) to know when each element is added/removed from the dom:

```
<script>
  Polymer('home-element', {
    attached: function() {
      console.log('home-element attached'); 
    },
    detached: function() {
      console.log('home-element detached'); 
    }
  });
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/zeyoyisu/1/edit

Comment: Great exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Polymer, rather than listening out for the `WebComponentsReady` event, try `polymer-ready`. It's a recent event we introduced that is fired when your elements are loaded and ready to go. Quick [demo](http://jsbin.com/teyoj/2/edit).

For your specific element, can you try the above and let us know if you're still running into issues? You could also try firing a custom event with `this.fire()` from inside your `research-element` as soon as you know it's ready.

Comment: So I tried that and I realize I might be doing something wrong: I am listening for the 'polymer-ready' event, inside my research-element ready method. Then when it is ready, I want to do stuff. (see edits on my original post)

Comment: So yes, no luck yet, still not working. Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: Both event are not triggered, seems if there any error in internal, the event will not trigger, but the error will not report on console.(e.g. miss import).I moved all WebComponentsReady to my-app.read()